# Extract a random sentence from article

Tags: php

how can i extract a random sentence from the second part of an article??

For Example, i'll have this article:

> The “History of the Chinese Communist Party, Volume 1,” the first entry in the Party’s official autobiography, appeared in 2002. Its authors had the luxury of hewing to a narrative of birth, growth, and triumph, covering the years between 1921 and the revolution, in 1949. After that, history gets dicier.
>
> Volume 2, on the period from 1949 to 1978, had to tiptoe through a chronological minefield of purges, famine, policy disasters, and other awkward artifacts of history that many living officials would prefer to leave unexamined. The volume, a thousand and seventy-four pages long, was edited for sixteen years. It needed four major rewrites. It was vetted and scrubbed by sixty-four different government and Party agencies, and then received line edits from the most powerful families mentioned in its pages.
>
> By the time it was released, in 2011, only one of the original three editors, Shi Zhongquan, had lived long enough to see it in print. “Writing history is not easy,” he said to the journalist Andrew Higgins. For all of the editors’ labors, the reception from independent scholars was not flattering; the official history explained that, once Chairman Mao’s Great Leap Forward drove the nation into famine, he “worked hard to correct” the mistakes, a judgment that a Dutch scholar called a “barefaced lie.”
>
> Volume 3 has yet to be written, but historians should prepare for an even knottier process. It will cover a period that includes not only China’s historic economic boom but also the bloody crackdown that ended the demonstrations at Tiananmen Square in 1989, an event that has turned out to be among the most thoroughly and systematically suppressed memories in the history of official histories. Initially, the problem with Tiananmen was not that it was documented too little. There were so many eyewitness accounts that, as Louisa Lim writes in her new book, “The People’s Republic of Amnesia,” “publishing houses worldwide were rejecting them, citing the saturation of the market.” At the time, a dissident named Fang Lizhi predicted that the sheer volume of documentation would force a “failure of the ‘Technique of Forgetting History,’ ” which had been so essential to Party control.

I don't know if that is possible, but i'd like to grab a short sentence from 3th or 4th paragraph.

The rules that i imagine would be something like that:

```
- Split the article in two blocks and use the second one.
- Extract every sentence after "fullstop".
- Dump sentences too lenght.
- Print a random sentence.
```

Is it too crazy?

I tried to adapt some function that i found on the web, but i always failed! :(

Is there a way?

Thank you at all,
sorry for my bad english!

Comment: What if abbreviations are use in the text? They contain a `.` (fullstop). This would break your algorithm.

Comment: First you have to define, in English, how you define "a sentence."

Answer (score 0):

Explode the entire paragraph with `"."` as the delimiter. Each sentence goes as an array element in the resulting array.

Then just use the `array_rand ($array, $number)` function with $number equal to 1 since you want one sentence. You'll get a random `index`. then use `array[ extracted random index]` to get the sentence.

Comment: You'd need to trim the whitespace too.

Comment: Once you have an array, just use `array_shuffle` and pop off whatever is at the end.

Comment: array_rand ($array, $number) returns one or more ($number) elements from an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use the explode function to split the text into its parapraphs.

```
$blocks = explode ('\n\n' , $text );
```

You will have to try a little bit what to use maybe \n\n is not correct.

Then take the second item of the array and split it again:

```
$frases = explode ('.', $blocks[1]);
```

Then take a random item from the array

```
$result = array_rand ( $frases, 1 );
```

Comment: It's really good but before how can i split my article in 2 parts and use just the second one? Thank you!

Comment: You are doing this with the first 'Explode'. This will create an array with one element per parapraph. Since arrays start from 0 you will have then to take the element where the key is 1 like I did in my code. \n\n is the code for two line breaks in a row which indicates that a new paragraph begins. But might be something diferent in you case. You'll have to try.